# datetick affecting figure dimensions

Tags: matlab, plot

I have several time series that I am trying to analyse and I am plotting all the series in different subplots and scatter plots. The date vector I have is in Julian dates, and I am having some problems in visualising the dates without it affecting the figure quality. Consider the following:

```
dat = 1-(20-1).*rand(365,8);
dat2 = 1-(20-1).*rand(365,8);
time = datenum('2009-01-01'):datenum('2009-12-31');

dtt = {'keepticks'};

for i = 1:8;
    for ii = 1:2;
        figure(ii);
        ax = subplot(4,2,i);
        plot(time,dat(:,i),'k');
        hold on;
        plot(time,dat2(:,i),'r');
        if ii == 1;
            datetick('x','mmm','keepticks');
        else
            datetick('x','mmm');
        end
        AX = get(ax,'position');
        AX(3) = AX(3)./2;
        set(ax,'position',AX);

        axes('position',[AX(1)+AX(3) AX(2) AX(3) AX(4)]);
        scatter(dat(:,i),dat2(:,i));
    end
end
```

As you see, the difference between figure 1 and figure 2 is that in one I have specified to 'keepticks' (wwhich is what I would like to do), but the two final plot dimensions vary, the format of the plots should be like figure 2. Why is this happening? How could I use keepticks but also have the subplots to maintain their dimensions?

Comment: Can you please try to clarify what it is about figure 2 that you like better?

Comment: All I am trying to see if why does datetick change the dimensions i.e. height of the subplots. By using datetick in one of the figures it changes the height of the subplots. Surely the height of the subplots should remain the same

Comment: By 'height' do you mean vertical length of the subplot in the figure window or do you mean the scaling on the Y-axis?

Comment: Okay I tested it and see what you mean. That is strange but you're likely to get more help if you showed the minimal amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jerad yes, vertical length of the subplot, as in axes('position',[pos(1) pos(2) pos(3) pos(4)]) where pos(4) would be the height.